# Where Kcontext variables are saved? JBPM

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I'm tring to identify where kcontext variables are stored, I'm running kie-server on test and dev environment. Last week I make a full copy of TestDB to DevDB, the process has stored a backendUrl variable; I change all the ocurrences to the correct URL, restart de server, clean temp files but...

Here is the problem: when I make changes that involucres a notification, JBPN is calling to Test Backend. Thats why I'm asking where kcontext variables are saved.

I have look in VariableInstanceLog and TaskVariableImpl tables

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the value of a process variable backendUrl? Did you check it? What occurrences did you change and where? Thanks.

Comment: I changed all occurrences in those tables, also in value and oldValue columns. I have a variable named env which is a JSON that contains my backendUrl

Comment: Ok, what is the type of that variable if it is JSON? Is it a jBPM document?